# How to properly detect user IP address in PHP?

Tags: php

Consistent with plenty of other threads on StackOverflow, I use the following code to detect a user's IP address:

```
function get_ip_address(){
    foreach (array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR') as $key){
        if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true){
            foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip){
                $ip = trim($ip); // just to be safe

                if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) !== false){
                    return $ip;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code usually works just fine. However, I've recently come across situations where the above code is NOT properly detecting a user's IP address.

For example, I get the IP address 209.141.xxx.xxx when the user's IP addresss is 184.105.xxx.xxx. 209.141.xxx.xxx is the IP address of a datacenter, so I thought they were using some sort of VPN and I can't get their real IP. Apparently they are using AdGuard, which isn't a VPN but does something pseudo VPN. But here's the thing. Even with AdGuard turned ON:

1) The website whatismyip.com shows 209.141.xxx.xxx for the user (just like my website using the above mentioned PHP code)

2) The website whatismyipaddress.com shows the users correct IP address 184.105.xxx.xxx

So apparently there is a way to get the correct IP address even when the user has something like AdGuard turned on, and my code is just doing it wrong?

Comment: The only reliable source of information is `REMOTE_ADDR` which is populated by the server, or the forwarding headers of a proxy you _explicitly_ trust, eg: your CDN or reverse proxy. Anyone with half a brain can slap a `X-Forwarded-For: 8.8.8.8` header into their request and your current code will just accept that as gospel fact. You should not be attempting to peer beyond a user's VPN or Proxy.

Comment: `'REMOTE_ADDR'` is last in your array so it will never be tested if any of the others has a valid IP.  Try listing `'REMOTE_ADDR'` first and others in order of reliability.

Comment: I've in the past used REMOTE_ADDR but that had its own problems, e.g., it showed the IP address of reverse proxy servers